# Minkowski functional on a convex set $M$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $E$ be a linear spcae over $\mathbb{R}$, let $M$ be a convex set and let $0\in M\subset E$. The *Minkowski functional* $p_M\colon E\to[0,\infty)\cup\{\infty\}$ is define by

$$
p_M(x):=\begin{cases}
0,\text{ if }x=0,\\
\infty,\text{ if there is no }t\in\mathbb{R}^+:x/t\in M, \\
\inf\{t\in\mathbb{R}^+:x/t\in M\},\text{ otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
The author then states that "if $0\leq p_M(x)<1$ then $x\in M$."

It's clear that if $p_M(x)=0$ then $x=0\in M$. Thus we can consider now the case when $0<p_M(x)<1$. This means there is a $t\in\mathbb{R}^+:x/t\in M$ and
$0<\inf\{t\in\mathbb{R}^+:x/t\in M\}<1$. Though, I don't see why this implies $x\in M$.

Comment: By the way, what functional analysis book do you read?

Comment: @Mark: The book is *Functional Analysis: An Introduction* by Eidelman-milman-tsolomitis

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought based on your last few questions. I had to work quiet a lot with this book while learning functional analysis.

Comment: @Mark: Glad to know I'm not alone! It's a good book, but the author(s) skip many logical steps in my opinion, which makes a self read more difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** By assumption there is some $0<t<1$ such that $\frac{x}{t}\in M$. Also, by definition we know that $0\in M$ and that $M$ is convex. Can you finish from here?

Comment: I did that at first, but then I thought we don't know that $0<t<1$, only that $0<\inf\{t\in\mathbb{R}^+:x/t\in M\}<1$. Why does this imply $0<t<1$?

Comment: As you stated, there is some $t>0$ such that $\frac{x}{t}\in M$. If all such values of $t$ would be $\geq 1$ then the infimum would be at least $1$ as well.

Comment: Ah so silly...thank you!